# sql server date is not converting into any style

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I am trying to convert the `date` to 102 styling it isn't working. The column hold `varchar` datatype

```
select convert(varchar(50),datecol,102) from table
```

Comment: this is wat the column holds
22-07-2019
31-10-2019
18-07-2019
21-11-2019
04-11-2019
11-11-2019
18-11-2019
30-09-2019
16-10-2019
11-11-2019

Any help would really appreciate it.

Comment: You can only convert to one type at a time, so `convert(varchar(50)date,datecol,102)` doesn't make sense. And the style you have is `105` not `102`, so you probably want `convert(date, datecol, 105)`. And you should consider changing the schema and make the type of `datecol` to `date`, that way you don't need any conversion and make sure only valid dates are stored in the table.

Comment: `select convert(varchar(50)date,datecol,102) from table` isn't valid syntax. Also comments are not the place for sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `date` and then back to `varchar`:

```
select convert(varchar(10), convert(date, datecol, 103), 102)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=347d9608eb37f9225b91659630c23e3a).
Result for `22-07-2019`:

```
2019.07.22
```

Comment: i did bro but it is failing to convert to date. thanks...

Comment: I'm guessing then, that not all your values are in the format you *think* they are, @AlukuchiAbhilash. This is one reason why storing dates as a `varchar` is a bad idea.

Comment: Did you check the demo? Of course it converts to **varchar** not to date.

Comment: @AlukuchiAbhilash dates do not have a format. The conversion you want is to varchar not date.

Comment: actually it converted ... thanks... earlier i tried with cast to date and convert for styling. it didnt worked for some reason.. thanksss again @forpas